# Adding viewstate to new instance of page (.Net)

Tags: .net, response.redirect

I develop an Aspx-page and when some control on the page is triggered, 
I want to redirect the browser to a new instance of the page,
adding some url-parameters. But I also would like to restore possible
changes, which the user might have made between first visiting the page 
and clicking on the control which caused the Response.Redirect. If I just
redirect, the changes are lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Server.Transfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525800%28VS.90%29.aspx) instead.